# It's a... Ohh... puzzle (BpFp)

Tags: word, knowledge, visual

I'm looking for a 5-letter word.

---

```
 100100100100
 100
 100
 100   100100
 100      100
 100100100100




 000000000000
 0
 0
 000000000000
            0
            0
 000000000000
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Maybe someone was thinking about https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Some are just like that. Same in other platforms. Especially in this case, he barely even saw the puzzle :D

Comment: I think the downvote is completely unwarranted. This puzzle is very different from the "boring old cipher" puzzles mentioned in that Meta post (puzzles like [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/116165/79067)). Anyway, here's +1 for you, @Prim3numbah, for the good puzzle :-)!

Comment: @DertereuuiFloireiurtrthr Yea, pretty odd to just downvote a puzzle (of this type) within ~2 mins. No worries though :)

Comment: @JLee Word tag added

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After trying so many wrong ideas, I decided to figure out what bp and fp meant in the title.

The 5-letter word could be

> **Water**, since its boiling point is 100 and its freezing point is zero. The G stands for gas and the S stands for solid. And the "ohh" in the title is a great clue that I didn't catch ( thx Amoz).

Nice puzzle. Thank you.

Comment: Hi it's me again, would G and S stand for Tnf naq Fbyvq, gur gjb fgngr bs znggre gb juvpu jngre gheaf vagb ng gur jevggra grzcrengher (naq haqre abezny cerffher)

Comment: I figured out g and s right after i answered. Thx tho

Comment: Nice! And Ohh...

Comment: Well done! All good. Thanks, h-h-o-pefully you liked it :)

Comment: Gur gvgyr vf "Vg'f n... Buu... chmmyr (OcSc)", fb V guvax OcSc vf sbe obvyvat cbvag naq serrmvat cbvag?  rot13

Comment: @Number Basher Yep, that's what I first figured out which led me to realize the rest.